# cf ldap accessing RACF

Tags: coldfusion, ldap, racf

Can ColdFusion 8, through LDAP, access IBM mainframe security system such as RACF?

Comment: RACF can expose an LDAP interface.  But you need to configure the RACF system to do it.  If so, should be able to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about RACF specifically, but you should be able to access any DB that has ODBC drivers available.  After downloading special ODBC drivers, i was able to connect to mainframe teradata.